# Use custom module template for content type page?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm finding lots of examples for theming the node template of a content type, but I can't figure out how to use a template from my module as the page template for a custom node type.

Answer (score 1):

[**page.tpl.php**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7.x) doesn't know, by itself, anything about node types so you'll have to make your module preprocess the page with [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x) to add an alternative theme hook suggestion.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['node']->type;
    }
}
```

Once done, you can have your module evoke [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x) to advertise processing for your custom page node type template and its location. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['page__mynodetype'] = array(
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'page--mynodetype',
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

When the module is enabled (and theme registry cache cleared), the theme engine will look for **page--mynodetype.tpl.php** within the templates directory of your module.

Comment: I'm not looking for a node template, but rather a page template.

Comment: Updated, same idea but with an additional function to make page templates aware of node types.